# Unit test keeps failing due to order of URLQueryItems

Tags: swift, unit-testing, dictionary, xctestcase

I have a unit test that is passing / failing randomly

```
func test_WhenRequestHasURLParams_CorrectlyEncodesParams() {
    sut.call(endpoint: MockEndpoint.endpointOne(paramOne: "foo", paramTwo: "bar")) { (response: MockResponse) in }
    XCTAssertEqual(mockURLSession.urlComponents?.percentEncodedQuery, "keyOne=4Plus5%3DNine&keyTwo=foo")
}
```

This is happening because the order my `percentEncodedQuery` keeps changing, when I run my tests.

I have an encoder I use as part of creating my request object, in this case it is

```
public struct URLParameterEncoder: ParameterEncoder {
    public static func encode(urlRequest: inout URLRequest, with parameters: Parameters) throws {
        guard let url = urlRequest.url else { throw NetworkError.missingURL }

        if var urlComponents = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false), !parameters.isEmpty {
            urlComponents.queryItems = [URLQueryItem]()

            for (key, value) in parameters {
                let queryItem = URLQueryItem(name: key,value: "\(value)")
                urlComponents.queryItems?.append(queryItem)
            }
            urlRequest.url = urlComponents.url
        }

        if urlRequest.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") == nil {
            urlRequest.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        }
    }
}



public typealias Parameters = [String: Any]

public protocol ParameterEncoder {
    static func encode(urlRequest: inout URLRequest, with parameters: Parameters) throws
}

public enum ParameterEncoding {
    case urlEncoding, jsonEncoding, urlAndJsonEncoding

    public func encode(urlRequest: inout URLRequest, bodyParams: Parameters?, urlParams: Parameters?) throws {
        do {
            switch self {
            case .urlEncoding:
                guard let urlParams = urlParams else { return }
                try URLParameterEncoder.encode(urlRequest: &urlRequest, with: urlParams)

            case .jsonEncoding:
                guard let bodyParams = bodyParams else { return }
                try JSONParameterEncoder.encode(urlRequest: &urlRequest, with: bodyParams)

            case .urlAndJsonEncoding:
                guard let bodyParams = bodyParams, let urlParams = urlParams else { return }
                try URLParameterEncoder.encode(urlRequest: &urlRequest, with: urlParams)
                try JSONParameterEncoder.encode(urlRequest: &urlRequest, with: bodyParams)
            }
        } catch {
            throw NSError(domain: "Could not encode request", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot work out why the order keeps changing

Comment: Is the order changing for the exact same `parameters` set (if so, perhaps you can share example), or is it just not respecting the order, that the order changes based upon the keys (which makes complete sense, because dictionaries, such as `Parameters` type, do not respect order)?

Comment: Completely unrelated, but those five lines initializing and appending the `queryItems` could be replaced with one line: `urlComponents.queryItems = parameters.map { URLQueryItem(name: $0.key, value: "\($0.value)") }`. But that won't have any impact on your question here.